# React: Big Calendar Font Style

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have been trying to search through the files of react big calendar but no luck. Is there a way to change the font style of text in the react big calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by targeting the `.rbc-calendar` class in your stylesheet.

```
.rbc-calendar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

This class covers the entire React Big Calendar.